# How to use Pandas to calculate difference in sales prices at different times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of 8,000 transactions. The assets have all sold / resold at least twice. Each transaction has a sales date. Each transaction has a unique identifier. The resales share a common identifier (TaxID). I would like to calculate the difference between the sale price for each common identifier by taking the date of the sale into account.

E.g. Asset 1 sold 1 Jan 2021, then again 15 Jan 2022. TaxID is common to the two. How do I calculate across these 8000 rows the difference in sale price between common identifiers? Some sold 3 or 4 times.

[image: ex dataframe]

Comment: Please provide a sample DF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('transactions.csv')

grouped = df.groupby('TaxID')

grouped = grouped.sort_values('sale_date')

df['diff'] = grouped['sale_price'].diff()
```

Using Pandas, you can calculate the difference in sale price between common identifiers by first grouping your transactions by their shared identifier (TaxID). This will create groups of transactions that have the same TaxID. Then, you would sort these groups by their sale date to ensure they are in chronological order. After that, you can use the diff() method to find the difference in sale price between each group of transactions with the same TaxID. This will give you the difference in sale price between each resale of an asset.

Comment: Thank you. This solution pointed me in the right direction.